# R: Improving the Performance of Joins With Stringdist

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the two following tables:

```
set.seed(123)
strings <- replicate(3, paste(sample(c(LETTERS, letters, 0:9), 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))


table1 = data.frame(zipcode = c(111,111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333))
table1$name <- sample(strings, nrow(table1), replace = TRUE)

table2 = data.frame(zipcode = c(111, 111, 111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333))
table2$name <- sample(strings, nrow(table2), replace = TRUE)

   corrupt_name <- function(name) {
    chars <- unlist(strsplit(name, ""))
    for (i in seq_along(chars)) {
        p <- runif(1)
        if (p < 0.05) {
            chars[i] <- sample(c(LETTERS, letters, 0:9), 1)
        }
    }
    paste(chars, collapse = "")
}

table1$name <- sapply(table1$name, corrupt_name)
table2$name <- sapply(table2$name, corrupt_name)
```

**My Question:** Only where the ZIP codes match in both tables, I want to perform a "fuzzy match" to find potential pairs of names (e.g. levenstein distance less than 5). In particular, I am trying to optimize the performance (i.e. speed) of my code.

So far, this is what I am doing:

```
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)

result <- merge(table1, table2, by.x = "zipcode", by.y = "zipcode") %>%
    mutate(dist = stringdist(name.x, name.y, method = "lv")) %>%
    filter(dist < 5)
```

The code seems to run fine without errors and produce a reasonable result. However, I am still wondering if I am doing this correctly and if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can try with base R `adist`

Comment: @ Ric: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, could you please show me how to use this? thanks!